# Infinitely many solutions for $\phi(n+2) = \phi(n) + 2$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function

A friend of mine gave me a number theoretical problem the other day:

Show that there are infinitely many solutions to this equation ($n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\phi$ is Euler's totient function):

$\phi(n+2)=\phi(n)+2$.

What I know is that twin primes $(n,n+2)$, doubles of Mersenne primes $n=2\cdot (2^p - 1)$ where $2^p-1$ is a Mersenne prime, or Sophie Germain primes $n=4p$ where $p$ and $2p+1$ are both primes, satisfy this equation. But as far as I know, we don't know if there are infinitely many of any of these. (Correct me if I'm wrong...)

Can anyone give me a clue how to prove/solve this exercise?

Comment: unclear for the variables, for example, is that a vector?

Comment: This is [A001838](https://oeis.org/A001838).  Is the result known?  I wouldn't have thought so.

Comment: Unbelievable which sequences are in OEIS ! I am over and over again baffled.

Comment: @Peter Agreed. OEIS has helped me identify patterns numerous times. Even if I only have two or three terms, sometimes it is enough.

Answer (score 1):

The exercise demands a (rigorous) proof and there is none , unless I missed infinite many "sporadic" solutions , solutions not fitting in one of the three families (although upto $10^9$ , the only one is $18$).

Although , almost surely there are infinite many twin-primes and also extremely likely infinite many Sophie-Germain-primes and finally probably infinite many Mersenne-primes , we cannot rule out that all families are finite , so I agree you and see no possibility for an unconditional proof.